# Bootstrap - Row of icons to flow to second line (make responsive)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4, and trying to create a (responsive) row of 12 icons.

```
<div class="app-container">
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-1">
    <a class="" href="https://www.xxx.org.au">
      <img class="" src="/images/web-1.png" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
  ... x 12

</div>
</div>
```

And the class "app-container" has one style property:

```
.app-container {
  width:1050px;
}
```

On a wide display the icons stay in a single row.

But as the window decreases in width, I'd like the icons to start falling into a second row (starting with the icons on the right end) one at a time.

At present they just stay how they are as things behind reduce in width.
(They basically look like they overflow outside the container they are in. They are not being fluid/responsive).

See below:

[image]

Comment: You have to use custom layout here as the columns are parent and they have fixed with in percentages that add up to make 100% . So you have to make it a custom layout with variable width .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Easiest solution** is to use the classes built into Bootstrap 4.

http://www.codeply.com/go/MvnOs3GPCC

```
<div class="app-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1">
            <a class="" href="https://www.xxx.org.au">
                <img class="" src="//placehold.it/60" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <a class="" href="https://www.xxx.org.au">
                <img class="" src="//placehold.it/60" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <a class="" href="https://www.xxx.org.au">
                <img class="" src="//placehold.it/60" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <a class="" href="https://www.xxx.org.au">
                <img class="" src="//placehold.it/60" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <a class="" href="https://www.xxx.org.au">
                <img class="" src="//placehold.it/60" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <a class="" href="https://www.xxx.org.au">
                <img class="" src="//placehold.it/60" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <a class="" href="https://www.xxx.org.au">
                <img class="" src="//placehold.it/60" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <a class="" href="https://www.xxx.org.au">
                <img class="" src="//placehold.it/60" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <a class="" href="https://www.xxx.org.au">
                <img class="" src="//placehold.it/60" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <a class="" href="https://www.xxx.org.au">
                <img class="" src="//placehold.it/60" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <a class="" href="https://www.xxx.org.au">
                <img class="" src="//placehold.it/60" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <a class="" href="https://www.xxx.org.au">
                <img class="" src="//placehold.it/60" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/MvnOs3GPCC)

Just set a `min-width` on each `col-1`. Don't use `col-md-1` beause they'll all stack at `992px` instead of "one at a time".

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm looking for, Ill have a play with this and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this solution:

```
 .col-md-1 { display: inline-block }
```

or this very different solution

```
 .col-md-1 { float:left }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change,

```
.app-container { width:1050px; }
```

to

```
.app-container { max-width:1050px; width:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `.container` class to you `.app-container` div. That should do the trick. Here's the basic layout for Bootstrap columns:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the div="container" before the div="row" inside the .app-container div.

Answer (score 0):

Final Solution Using Bootstrap Grid

```
.app-container{max-width: 1050px;}
.col-md-1{border:1px solid #ccc;}

<div class="row">
<div class="app-container">
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">2</div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">4</div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">5</div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">6</div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">7</div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">8</div>  
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">9</div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">10</div>    
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">11</div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">12</div>
</div>
```

Comment: OK Ill try this

Comment: Nope, I added this to the class but they are still all staying on the same line.

Comment: Still not changing

Comment: Its just working http://fiddle.jshell.net/mbjdhuq8/2/ may be you missed something

Comment: I looked at the fiddle, it shows 12 columns that grow and shrink in width - thats not what I'm trying to do. As the screen width shrinks I want each icon to stay the same but drop to the next line as the app-container shrinks.

Comment: so you have to use proper bootstrap classes to make it responsive any way i update it http://fiddle.jshell.net/mbjdhuq8/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
  <style>
   .app-container{
       max-width : 1050px;
   }
   .a{
      display: inline-block;
      float : left;
      width : 100px;
      height : 100px;

   }
   .a img{
       width :80px;
       height : 80px;
   }
   </style>
   <div class="app-container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="a">
          <a class="" href="https://www.xxx.org.au">
           <img class="" src="/images/web-1.png" alt="">
          </a>
       </div>
        ...x 12
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Try this @TimothyAURA